# How to filter a multi-index dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, countif

I have two dataframes, one bigger, with names and family names, defined as a multi-index (Family and name) dataframe:

```
                Age   Weight 
Family   Name
         Marge
SIMPSON  Bart
         Lisa    
         Homer

         Harry
POTTER   Lilian
         Lisa
         James
```

And the another df is smaller, containing just some of the names of the first df:

```
Family   Name
SIMPSON  Lisa
SIMPSON  Bart
POTTER   Lisa
```

I want to filter the first df to show just the names that exists in the second df.
To a better explain, as a reference, in Excel I would create an extra colum and type (suposing that second df is in Sheet2)
`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:Sheet2!A,A1,Sheet2!B:Sheet2!B,B1)`
Than I would filter rows that are equal to 1 in the created column.
Ps: I am not asking how to replicate exaclty the excel code, because I know that propably there's a simple way to do in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `join`

```
df2.join(df1, on=df1.index.names).set_index(df1.index.names)

              Age Weight
Family  Name            
SIMPSON Lisa  NaN    NaN
        Bart  NaN    NaN
POTTER  Lisa  NaN    NaN
```

---

#### `merge`

```
 df1.merge(df2, on=df1.index.names).set_index(df1.index.names)

              Age Weight
Family  Name            
SIMPSON Lisa  NaN    NaN
        Bart  NaN    NaN
POTTER  Lisa  NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `df1` have multiple index , so normal filter will not work , we can try `reindex`

```
df1 = df1.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2))
```

Comment: Before I scrolled down, this is what I thought of and I knew I'd find this answer with you having providing it (-:

Answer (score 0):

Let `df1` be the bigger dataframe with `MutiIndex` and `df2` smaller one with names.

Then you could do something like this:

```
names = set(df2.Name.astype(str).values)
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.get_level_values('Name').isin(names)]
```